# Error with GoogleApi in GetCampaigns

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I have a problem with the google adwords API. I downloaded the lib googleads-php-lib in the newest version.

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib

Everything works fine. I got the refresh token. I put it in the auth.ini like the client_id and the client_secret id.

But now I need a developerToken. Where do I get it? When I want to test it with the GetCampaigns.php, an error occurs.

> An error has occurred: [QuotaCheckError.INVALID_TOKEN_HEADER @ ]

Answer (score 0):

You need to signup for the AdWords API here https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/signingup after your signup application is reviewed and approved you'll get your developer token.